# Get only one element from array of objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

How can I get only the name from JSON file. Also code is perfectly working for getting the data from "file.json" i.e. that's not the problem for sure.

JavaScript:

```js
var data = [];
function getName() {
  //what should I write here to get only name from the first object i.e. John
  //with this: data[0].name I am getting error!
}

var xhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
else
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xhttp.readyState == 4) {
    data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    getName();
  }
}

xhttp.open("GET","file.json",true);
xhttp.send();
```

"file.json" - JSON:

```js
[
  {
    "name":"John",
    "city":"London"
  },
  {
    "name":"Maria",
    "city":"Rome"
  }
]
```

Comment: (Instead of `onreadystatechange` and `readyState`, you can just use `onload`.)

Comment: Works fine for me, as in, no error. What's your error? https://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/0xf62ny6/ logs the entire data object, and then `data[0].name`

Comment: What's the error? Why are you using a global variable instead of passing the value to the function?

Comment: Yes, yes finally it worked, I was having other line of code which was making the error, with data[0].name is working now!

Comment: @FelixKling because that is the school way I learned from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the variable data through the function

```
var data = [];
function getName(data) {
  return data[0].name;
}

var xhttp;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
else
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xhttp.readyState == 4) {
    data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    getName(data);
  }
}

xhttp.open("GET","file.json",true);
xhttp.send();
```

Also, if you want to retrieve all names, you can do something like this :

```
function getName(data) {
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      names.push(data[i].name);
  }
  return names;
}
```

(The data is the array data)

Comment: it give only first name of index

Comment: of course, but it does not that do you wanted? Or you want to return an array of names?

Comment: i think the the author of this question is looking to get all name in json file not looking to get only single name

Answer (score 5):

Use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transfrom items of your array:

```
data.map(function(item) {
    return item.name
});
```

Comment: Is this jQuery function ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `getName` function should look like this:

```
function getName(){
  a.forEach(function(i,j){
     console.log(i.name);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that `JSON` datatypes are directly mapped to standard javascript datatypes. That means there's no such thing as JSON array, once you `JSON.parse()` a string, then you get plain javascript primitives: arrays, objects, strings, numbers, etc.

So getting an element from a JSON array is just accessing an element of a standard javascript array. This is usually achieved by square brackets operator `var element = array[index]`.

Your code is however broken in several parts which are unrelated to array element access.

First, you define the `data` variable at the toplevel - you just don't need it there (at least according to the sample).

Then, you initialize it with an empty array - I have no idea why.

Your `onreadystatechange` callback is simple when expressed in words: you get a string, parse it as json and then call `getName` supplying the result. That means your `getName()` should require a `data` argument which you then access within the function.